# How to move mouse pointer in linux in xwindow?

Tags: mouse, x11

Could anyone tell me how to mouse xwindow library to move mouse pointer . I read some posts which asked me to write to mouse device file available in /dev . But for some purpose i have to use xwindow library only .

Answer (score 1):

Got this code from an open source project to move the pointer to (x,y) co-ordinate on the screen.

```
#define SENSITIVITY 3        
static void movePointerTo(int x, int y){
        Bool result;
        int root_x, root_y, win_x, win_y; 
            unsigned int mask_return;
        root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);
            Window window_returned;
        result = XQueryPointer(dpy, root, &window_returned, &window_returned, &root_x, &root_y, &win_x, &win_y,
                    &mask_return);
            if (result != True) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "No mouse found.\n");
                        return;
            }
            XWarpPointer(dpy, None,root, 0, 0, 0, 0, root_x+(x*SENSITIVITY),root_y+(y*SENSITIVITY));
        XFlush(dpy);
    }
```